# Get courses from Spring Social LinkedIn API

Tags: spring, linkedin-api, spring-social, spring-social-linkedin

People often list their taken courses from universities at linkedIn.

Does anyone know if it is possible to fetch these courses using Spring Social?

im using:

```
<org.springframework.social-version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</org.springframework.social-version>
<org.springframework.social.linkedin-version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</org.springframework.social.linkedin-version>     
<org.springframework-version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
<org.springframework.security-version>3.1.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.security-version>
```

The closest I found is the education object, but it doesn't seem to contain the courses.

```
linkedin.profileOperations().getUserProfileFull().getEducations()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now there is no support for fetching courses.

However, I added a improvement issue in spring socials tracker [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SOCIALLI-34)

And I found an alternative way of fetching the courses by rest operations.

```
    Connection<LinkedIn> connection = connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(LinkedIn.class);
    if (connection != null) {
        LinkedIn linkedin = connection.getApi();
        String url = String.format("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=%s:(courses)", linkedin.profileOperations().getProfileId()); 
        String jsonData = linkedin.restOperations().getForObject(url, String.class);

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonData).getJSONObject("courses");
        JSONArray courseArray = obj.getJSONArray("values");
        JSONObject course = courseArray.getJSONObject(0);

        String name = course.getString("name");
        System.out.println("This is the name of the first course: " + name);
    }
```

To see what university a course belongs to seems hard. Couldn't solve that part.